# QML TextInput fails to render UTF-8 bullet character

Tags: qt, utf-8, qml

I have a simple QML `TextInput` component having `echoMode` property set to `TextInput.Password`. I see that default `passwordCharacter` (it should be a medium bullet (U+25CF)) is not correctly rendered (see image).

[image]

This happens when application is built for a target running a Yocto Poky distro. If I build on my host, the bullet is shown correctly. I suppose this is a locale related problem but i can't figure out the reason and i don't know exactly how QML interacts with locale settings on the system. I'm able to print bullet character from a shell on target with command:

```
echo -e "\u25cf"
```

so i suppose that locale related settings are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have some incorrect settings. Check the [font.family](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#font.family-prop) to be sure that it supports Unicode. Try another font, one from the list returned from [fontFamilies()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#fontFamilies-method). Check the current locale using [Qt.locale()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-locale.html#details).

Comment: Make sure your font actually has that glyph in it.

Comment: Hi, the font is exactly the same since it is embedded in the binary through .qrc file and no changes are made to sources.